# SSRS - Dynamically changing calendar parameters

Tags: ssrs-2008

Suppose that we have a report with two date parameters: StartDate and EndDate selectable by calendar-picker not through a drop-down values list.
But I need to implement a condition for these two parameters:

1. If I set StartDate > EndDate, automatically StartDate must changed to EndDate value (in the StartDate textbox).
2. If I set EndDate < StartDate, automatically EndDate must changed to StartDate value (in the EndDate textbox)

In other words, StartDate<=EndDate no matter where I setting-up these values, from StartDate textbox or EndDate textbox.
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard SSRS report viewer, you can't. Parameters can be dependent only in one way, so for example you can validate enddate every time you set startdate, but not the other way around. To bypass this, either write your own reportviewer control or use report-level validattion, e.g. when user picks wrong dates display a "wrong dates selected" message in the report instead of a data.